# SQL & Pandas Efficiency

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

Quick question. What is the rule of thumb when deciding where to begin manipulating data? Should I do it when I am hitting the database? Or, just bring everything into my data frame and .drop from there? I also need to rearrange the columns in 4 separate data frames to union them into one data source once finished. With that in mind, is it easier to rearrange in the SQL or pandas? I know this is trivial, but I appreciate any help.

Comment: If your data fits into memory and you are loading it into data frames anyway, then use the tool that you are most familiar with.  If the data doesn't fit into memory, you have little choice but to use Pandas.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing everything in python. What I meant was when I connect and extract data, is it more efficient manipulate the data in the SQL query or after I have it in my data frame...

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have seen sql performing better than pandas on larger data *curious* :)

Comment: I think SQL queries will outperform pandas data manipulation. I would do everything I can in SQL including joins and then load the data into pandas. Since you can create temporary tables in SQL, it has quite some power in data manipulation.

Comment: Do everything you can to limit the amount of data that leaves database; passage over an interim network is usually the slowest part of the process

Comment: @TYZ, thanks. I will move my more simple ETL functions to the query. I do have a few things I needed to create functions for and will likely keep that where it is.  I am currently pulling a few million lines from 9 tables and performing several basic transformations. It is taking about 160 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is single-threaded. No matter what your compute power is, you only take advantage of a single core.
SQL Sever is multi-threaded.
If you are dealing with large data sets, performance-wise you would be better doing the processing on the SQL Server side.

P.S.
There are attempts to expose a multi-threaded Pandas API such as [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html), [Modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin) and [Koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas)